# Google Maps for iPhone: how to disable "My location"?

Tags: iphone, ios, google-maps

So, I have Google Maps for iPhone (not the latest 4.0.x version, but the immediately previous one), and there's an arrow on the bottom right which enables "My location". When it's enabled (the arrow turns blue), the map is always centered in your current location…

…Except that sometimes it becomes stuck in that view. If I press on the arrow again, it enables the perspective view (similar to Apple Maps' aerial view). If I then hit it again, it goes back to the normal view… but "My location" is still enabled. If I drag to another place of the map, it immediately snaps back to my current location. It's extremely annoying, and the only way to "disable" it is to force-quit Google Maps and start again.

The weird thing is that this only happens sometimes, not every time I hit the arrow. What did I do wrong to enable that "feature" permanently, and how can i exit it in those cases?

Comment: hmm… mine used to do that sometimes - I'd guess the answer is to update it to the latest version

Comment: Glad to see that I wasn't the only one. t just updated to 4.1.0 in my iPhone, and will update here if it happens again...